Constrain depending joint angles - Trajectory Planning with Drake Direct Collabration - Robotics
The goal is to prevent the end effector from reaching a certain area
Initial:
dircol = DirectCollocation(acromonk_plant,
                                    acromonk_plant.CreateDefaultContext(),
                                    num_time_samples=30,
                                    minimum_timestep=0.01,\
                                    maximum_timestep=0.5,
                                    input_port_index = acromonk_plant.get_actuation_input_port().get_index())

# Add Equal time interval constraint so that DirectCollocation doesn't stretch/shrink time
# in our trajectory.
_ = dircol.AddEqualTimeIntervalsConstraints()

I know how to block single joint angels:
state = dircol.state()
_ = dircol.AddConstraintToAllKnotPoints(state[1] >= np.deg2rad(-150))

I want to constrain multiple depending joint angles. Like so:
If theta1 is in Range 34°-36°, theta2 should be blocked in Range 116°-118°
How can I do that?
I also tried to use a barrier function. But i prefer this method. The documentation did not help.

The question is not very clear. Of course, you could call that method multiple times, e.g.
dircol.AddConstraintToAllKnotPoints(state[1] >= np.deg2rad(-150))
dircol.AddConstraintToAllKnotPoints(state[2] >= np.deg2rad(-116))

but I suspect you are asking about writing the vector form?  e.g. you'd like to write
dircol.AddConstraintToAllKnotPoints(state >= [0.1, 0.2])

if that's the case, then please see:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/8315#issuecomment-480773969
basically, you can do
from pydrake.all import ge
dircol.AddConstraintToAllKnotPoints(ge(state,[0.1, 0.2]))

you can do this for lt, le, eq, ne, ge, and gt.
